# Change display name of entity property when accessed through relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a `Fare` entity and a `Ticket` entity. Fares can belong to many tickets, tickets can only have one fair. In the fair entity I'm defining the name as so:

```
[Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(3)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The framework uses `Name` as the field name for the fare name, which is perfectly fine when I'm performing CRUD on fares. However, when I want to show the fare that's linked to a ticket, the framework still calls this property `Name`, and now it doesn't make sense. Take this screenshot as an example:

[image]

This page is showing a list of tickets, and the second column (called name) should be called "Fare".

I know I can change this by adding a `Display(Name = "Fare")` attribute to my `Fare` entity, but then the CRUD stuff for fares wouldn't make sense.

The only other way I can think of solving this is using a view model for this page, is there a better way?

Comment: Always use view models as they represent the view, simple and clean.

Comment: This entirely depends on the code for your view. Show that and we can help.